# Find & reload Edge browser window from VB script?

Tags: vbscript, microsoft-edge

We have a piece of VB script which runs outside a browser.  It looks for a browser window that is loaded from a specifc URL.  If it finds a match it changes the URL and reloads the browser window.  The script uses the .locationURL property to find the correct browser window.  This proprty no longer seems available to VB for Edge browser.

I am guessing this is because Edge no longer support VB script.  I was wondering if anyone knows any way around this issue or is there another scripting language that might work?

Comment: The IE Engine was available through VBScript via COM but as Edge is now Chromium it won't work. You should still have access through IE 11 though using `CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`.

Comment: Looks like it does thankyou.